# Change part of url of background-image using jquery

Tags: jquery, background-image

I have a dynamically created background-image for an embedded YouTube video. Now I want to change a part of the background-image url.

This is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="jet-video__overlay--custom-bg" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3xqE5F2zHQ/maxresdefault.jpg);">
```

Now I want to change the "maxresdefault" in the url with "hqdefault" using jquery.

This is what I tried so far:

```
 $('.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg').attr("style").replace('maxresdefault','hqdefault');
```

Comment: That's cool, but what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Shiz this is what I tried: $('.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg').attr("style").replace('maxresdefault','hqdefault');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.css('background-image')` and `replace` like this

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 $('.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg')         // element to set the background to it */
 .css('background-image' ,                   // use .css('background-image'
     $('.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg')     // element to get the background from it
     .css('background-image')                // get the background
     .replace('maxresdefault' , 'hqdefault') //replace it
  );
});
```

```css
.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg{
  width : 300px;
  height : 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jet-video__overlay--custom-bg" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3xqE5F2zHQ/maxresdefault.jpg);"></div>
```

Also as @Rory suggested <sup>Easy & Simple</sup> you can use `, (i , value) => return .replace....`

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 $('.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg')
 .css('background-image', (i, v) => v.replace('maxresdefault', 'hqdefault'));
});
```

```css
.jet-video__overlay--custom-bg{
  width : 300px;
  height : 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jet-video__overlay--custom-bg" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3xqE5F2zHQ/maxresdefault.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped .. Have a great day @CliffVandyck :-)

Comment: Just FYI this can be made more succinct with `$('.el').css('background-image', (i, v) => v.replace('maxresdefault', 'hqdefault'));`

Comment: @CliffVandyck answer updated with Rory suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan But it will not work without `return ....` :-)

Comment: It will as the arrow function has an implicit return statement.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry you're right .. Yes it works as you said without `{ }` and `;` .. Thanks